# Invalid value for<path> attribute d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a complete newbie in d3.js and I was working around with some code but it's failing to create the path. Please check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vatsalya25/knpzxv3f/

and kindly inform me where I am going wrong.

```
/*  */
    var setChartDimensions = function(l,r,t,b,w,h) {   
        /* Set the dimensions of the graph */
        margin = {
                left : l || 60,
                right : r || 110,
                top : t || 20,
                bottom : b || 40

        };
        getDimensions(w,h); //
        width = width - 100 - margin.left - margin.right;
        height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    };

    /*  */
    var setChartContainer = function(){
        svg = d3.select("#container")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        graph = svg.append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
    };

    var xAxis_true= 0, yAxisRight_true= 0, yAxisLeft_true= 0, array = [], width, height, svg, graph;
    var jsonArray=[], path, axis, time, noOfPoints = 20, tracker = 0;
    var color = d3.scale.category10();
    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([ 0, width ]);
    var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);
    var y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(5);
    var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y2).orient("right").ticks(5);
    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1).orient("left").ticks(5);

    /*  */
    var getDimensions = function(w,h) {
        width = w || $(window).innerWidth()/0.93;
        height = h || screen.height/2.7;
        $('#container').css('min-width', width);
        $('#container').css('min-height', height);
    };

    /*  */
    $(window).resize(function() {
        getDimensions();
    });



    /* Sets the points (x,y) for the path */
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.xValue);
    }).y(function(d) {
        return y1(d.yValue);
    });


    /*  */
    var setXdomain = function(data) {
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
            return d.xValue;
        }));
    }

    /*  */
    var setYdomain = function(data) {
        y1.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.yValue * 1.31;
        }) ]);

        y2.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.yValue * 0.9;
        }) ]);
    }

    /*  */
    var createPath = function(data) {
        path = graph.append("g")
        .append("path") // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));    
    }

    /*  */
    var addXAxis = function() {
        axis = graph.append("g") // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform","translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    }

    /*  */
    var addYAxis = function(i) {
        makeY = svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "yAxis")   
        .style("fill", "steelblue");

        if(i==0)
            makeY.call(yAxisLeft);
        else {
            makeY.attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)");
            makeY.call(yAxisRight);
        }
    }

    /*  */
    var makeXGrid = function (n) {
        xGrid = svg.selectAll("line.verticalGrid").data(x.ticks(n)).enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr({
            "class":"verticalGrid",
            "x1" : function(d){ return x(d);},
            "x2" : function(d){ return x(d);},
            "y1" : height,
            "y2" : 0,
            "fill" : "none",
            "shape-rendering" : "geometricPrecision",
            "stroke" : "#C8C8C8 ",
            "stroke-width" : "1px"
        });

    }

    /*  */
    var makeYGrid = function (a) {
        svg.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid").data(y1.ticks(10)).enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr({
            "class":"horizontalGrid",
            "x1" : 0,
            "x2" : width,
            "y1" : function(d){ if(a==0) return y1(d); else return y2(d);},
            "y2" : function(d){ if(a==0) return y1(d); else return y2(d);},
            "fill" : "none",
            "shape-rendering" : "geometricPrecision",
            "stroke" : "#C8C8C8 ",
            "stroke-width" : "1px"
        });
    }

    /*  */
    var addTitle = function(title) {
        svg.append("text") // Add the title shadow
        .attr("x", (width / 2))
        .attr("y", margin.top / 2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .text(title);

        svg.append("text") // Add the title
        .attr("class", "stock")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))
        .attr("y", margin.top / 2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .text(title);

    }

    /* Add the text label for the X axis */
    var xAxisLabel = function(text) {
        svg.append("text")      // Add the text label for the x axis
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        .text(text);
    }

    /* Add the text label for the Y axis */
    var yAxisLabel = function(text) {
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
            .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .style("font-size", "14px")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(text);
    }

    /* Function to insert Random points into the JSON */
    var makeRandomPoints = function(t) {
        time += 1000;
        return {
            "xValue" : Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)),
            "yValue" : Math.floor((Math.random() * 100))
        }
    }

    /* Function to create the chart */
    var createChart = function(title, xLabel, yLabel, data, realtime, gridX, xG, gridY, yG) {
        setChartDimensions(left=null, right=null, top=null, bottom=null, width=null, height=null); /* Pass values in the order left right top bottom */
        setChartContainer();

        setXdomain(data);       /* Set the domain of X Axis */
        setYdomain(data);       /* Set the domain of Y Axes */
        createPath(data);       /* create the line (path) for the data */
        addXAxis();
        addYAxis(0);
        if(gridX) {
            makeXGrid(xG);
        }
        if(gridY) {
            makeYGrid(yG);
        }
        addTitle(title);
        xAxisLabel(xLabel);
        yAxisLabel(yLabel);
    }

    /*  */
    var init = function () {

        for(var i=0; i<noOfPoints; i++) {
            array.push(makeRandomPoints());
        }
        console.log(array.length);
        // createChart("XYZ", "X Value", "Y Value", data, 1, 5);
        createChart("XYZ", "X Value", "Y Value", array, 0, true, 5, true, 5);

    }

    init();
```

Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,NaNCNaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaNSNaN,NaN,NaN,NaN"
Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="Mundefined,6V0H0V6"
Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"
...
and so on.

Comment: [This](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) link could help you about `svg path` in d3.

Comment: The wrong part is: `.attr("d", valueline(data));` you should made the `d` value as the pattern.

Comment: @Gabriel  Can you please elaborate what do you mean by making "d" value as the pattern.

Comment: In this example `<path d='M 10 25 L 10 75 L 60 75 L 10 25' />` we use pattern. `M` means  the begin point to drawing  in this case is `10 ,25` and `L` means draw line to, in this case will draw a line from `10,25 to 10,75`. you can find all of this in link of first comment.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/1ayd08uh/4/) is an example that I create to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scales are broken (width and height variables aren't defined until later calls):

```
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([ 0, width ]);
    var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);
    var y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);

    > undefined
    > undefined
```

Just move the `.range` calls into your `setDomain` functions.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knpzxv3f/1/).